# How to access or store form values for use in another function

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

## Issue Summary

What I'm trying to do is submit a form using the "Magic Form" Plugin on OctoberCMS and take the values submitted from that form and use them in another function.

### My attempt

I'm currently doing this in the 'Code' section of OctoberCMS. I just can't figure out how to access the $formdata from outside the event listener for 'martin.forms.beforeSaveRecord'.

```
<?php
use Event as Event;

function onInit() 
{    
$this['viewBag']->setProperty('redirectUrl', '/order_completed');


Event::listen('studioazura.stripe.setChargePostData', function($self, &$postData, $stripe, $invoice, $address) { 
    // override amount and description; add key to metadata 
    $postData['amount'] = 29.99 * 100; 
    $postData['description'] = 'My Overriden Description'; 
    $postData['metadata']['new_info'] = 'new value'; 
    $postData['metadata']['email'] = 'new value'; 
}); 

Event::listen('studioazura.stripe.handleStripeChargeResponse', function($self, $response, $redirect) { 
    // Send email to admin saying details have been collected
    $this->onSend();
}); 

// Event that returns the form data
Event::listen('martin.forms.beforeSaveRecord', function (&$formdata, $component) {
    // $this['viewBag']->setProperty('name', $formdata['name']);
    $this['result'] = $formdata['name'];
    // How do I access $formdata['name'] and the other fields in my onSend()
});
}

function onSend()
{
$vars = ['name' => 'Joe', 'user' => 'Mary'];
$name = $this['viewBag']->property('name');
$email = post('email');
$message = post('message');
$params = compact('name', $name);

Mail::send('testTemplate', $vars, function($message) {

    $message->to('myemail@email.ie', 'Admin Person');
    $message->subject('This is a reminder :: ' + $name);

});
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.